# Android actionbar icons as generated by android asset studio always appear deactivated

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-icons

I've been using the huge time-saver Android asset studio at http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html to help with taking my images and creating tab icons.

I'm now using the asset studio to generate actionbar icons for the options menu.  I've given it an image of color white with 80% opacity as specified in the design guidelines. The problem is that the images appears very dark, as if the icon is disabled.  In fact, on actual hardware, I cannot even tell the icons are on the screen.  (My theme is holo-dark, btw)  If I generate using the asset studio option 'menu icons' then then the icons are no longer so dark, but appear slightly too large.

The menu I'm creating is the one created through onCreateOptionsMenu.  Should I be using the menu icons or actionbar icon generator in the asset studio?  If actionbar icons, why do the icons always appear very dark?

Comment: Did you try changing the Theme when generating the icons using the Asset Studio? There's an option to switch between Holo Light and Holo Dark. With Holo Dark active, the output images are definitely white-ish, which leaves me to believe you might've used Holo Light (which will give quite dark icons).

Comment: Yep, that's where I went wrong, skipped right over that option.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing the Theme when generating the icons using the Asset Studio? There's an option to switch between Holo Light and Holo Dark. With Holo Dark active, the output images are definitely white-ish, which leaves me to believe you might've used Holo Light (which will give quite dark icons).